# Multithreading Flask App Throws Error with MRCNN

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, flask

I have a flask app running in **thread true mode**.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup.check_director()
    web_app.secret = "image-service"
    web_app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8084, debug=True, threaded=True)
```

I'm triggering **mrcnn**(https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) task using api call, The Predictor class looks like this

```
class Predictor(object):
    def __init__(self, config=None, weights=WEIGHTS_PATH, device=DEVICE):
        self.weights=weights
        self.config = ElementConfig() if config is None else config
        # self.el = Element_linker()

        self.logger.info("Loading Mask R-CNN model")
        print("Loading Mask R-CNN model and weights")
        start = time.time()

        self._graph = tf.Graph()

        with self._graph.as_default():
            self.model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=self.config)
            self.logger.info("Loading saved weights from {}".format(weights))
            self.model.load_weights(weights, by_name=True)
            self.init_g = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            self.init_l = tf.local_variables_initializer()
            print("Loading completed in %s seconds" % ((time.time() - start)))

    ....
    ....
    ....

    def predict(self):
        with tf.Session(graph=self._graph) as _session:
           _session.run(self.init_g)
           _session.run(self.init_l)
           results = _session.run(self.model.detect([image], verbose=0))

    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

The code works fine when there is one api call at a time. When I have multiple api hitting at the same time, the code throws error as:

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(7, 7, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Detailed Log: https://gist.github.com/amandalmia14/70b8b3fb13bef8f545d9963bd609f2f2

I have also tried using different ways of organizing sessions and graphs. Have also tried all the solutions present on mrcnn github issues page, but nothing helped.

***Is there an issue with threading or the approach mentioned above ?***